# Can I plot multiple species using multiple coord_map functions in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a csv with species occurences (in coordinates) that I mapped using ggplot and the code below.

I am pretty satisfied with the apperance but these all of these points are actually two plant species and I am trying to differentiate them in the map. The gent data set I refer to has coordinates for both species, should I separate them and then would I be able to add another `coord_map()` function to add the other species?

I have not yet tried to separate out the two species from the single csv.

Here is my code:

```
ilwi <- ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(
    data = w, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
    fill = "lightyellow", colour = "black"
  ) +
  coord_map() +
  geom_point(
    data = gent, aes(x = long2, y = lat2),
    colour = "royalblue3", size = 2, position = "identity"
  )
```

Comment: ilwi<-ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = w,
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
               fill = "lightyellow", colour = "black") +
  coord_map() +
  geom_point(data = gent,
             aes(x = long2, y = lat2),
             colour = "royalblue3", size = 2,
             position = "identity")

Comment: No. One plot, one coord. But as your data contains data for both species your data probably has a column containing the type of species? In that case you could map this column on the `color` aes to color your points by species, e.g. something like `geom_point(data = gent, aes(x = long2, y = lat2, color = NAME_OF_SPECIES_COLUMN), size = 2, position = "identity")`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am going to try this!

Comment: This did not work, unfortunately but I appreciate the advice! I will make a new post with more details.